# Should there only be a single AudioContext?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

In Web Audio do I have a single audio context for the entire program. Or do you have a different audio context for each channel?

Let's say I'm playing samples, playing a synth, and I'm also recording all at the same time. (I'm use recorder.js) Should this all be under a single audioContext?

```
var audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
```

Comment: The channels are set in a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer/getChannelData) in your audio context.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have very specific reasons for multiple contexts, I'd use just one.  Each context is independent from every other and you can't really connect them together in any way.

Your example isn't really clear on what you're trying to do and why you might want separate contexts.